# How to carry over existing wp users to a new buddypress installation

Tags: buddypress

I had made a community with a different plugin (I think it was mingle.
I recently installed buddypress, removed mingle and changed the site to suite. Now the problem is the existing users are not listed as members in the members page, only me, the admin. I have looked for, but not found, a solution. i am know how to use Wordpress but this one has stumped me. This may be an easy question for all those experienced buddypress users out there, but I am just starting, so keep that in mind before you say how completely dumb I am :)

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: This is not really going to be answerable without knowing how that "different plugin" managed users. It seems to have had its own internal system, but that is just a guess. Can you come up with more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following plugin will make all WordPress users to appear on BuddyPress members directory. It doesn't provide full migration of users, but it will update the `last_activity` user meta field that is used by BP to display users.

This is a plugin code, so you need to create a new php file (eg. `bp-add-users.php`) and upload it to plugins directory of your WP installation `wp-content/plugins`. When you *activate* the plugin it will update all users, after that you can deactivate and delete:

```
/*
Plugin Name:  BP User Updater
Description:  Update `last_activity` user meta for all users.
Author:       Ahmad M
 */

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_users_to_bp');

function add_users_to_bp() {

    $users = get_users();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_activity', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did what you said, added the plugin. Did not work! broke the website, had to deactivate, users still the same! Is this code you gave me wrong?

Comment: How exactly it broke the website? What messages/debug information it shows you? This code simply will get all your WP users, loop through them to update each `last_activity` field to the current date, and I have tested it with no issues. You also can hook `add_users_to_bp()` function above to `init` action in `functions.php` and visit your website once to trigger this update and after that delete the code from `functions.php` so it wont be triggered on each request (`add_action('init', 'add_users_to_bp');`).

Comment: First there's this at the top of the admin "The plugin generated 364 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

Comment: Also this every page "/* Plugin Name: BP User Updater Description: Update `last_activity` user meta for all users. Author: Ahmad M */ register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'add_users_to_bp'); function add_users_to_bp() { $users = get_users(); foreach ($users as $user) { update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_activity', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); } }
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dallas88/public_html/Apps4You/wp-content/plugins/bp-add-user/bp-add-users.php:16) in /home/dallas88/public_html/Apps4You/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876"

Comment: I did nothing to the function.php, I only added the plugin. Sorry for 3 comments, I cant fit all that code in a single comment.

Comment: When you copy the code to the new file you create, make sure there is no spaces before the opening php tag `<?php`. Any character or single space or new line between the opening `<?php` and the top of the page might caused that error, you need to put the `<?php` at the very beginning of the page.

Comment: You are awesome! You left out the `<?php` at the top, but once i put it back in..........it works! thanks alot, f you want to see that it worked go to http://www.apps4you.dallasinitiatives.com/members/ Thanks again!